# importar base de datos con php en consulta sql?

Tags: php, sql

Hola queridos amigos de la web el dia de hoy tengo un problema con un script que hace que el servidor se resetee, el problema esta en que yo puedo hacer que se borren las tablas del phpmyadmin pero lo que necesito es que al borrar todas las tablas de la base de edatos que este al mismo tiempo importe una nueva base de datos desde una consulta sql, aqui esta el codigo para que ustedes me ayuden por favor:

```
    <?php

    include_once("../../GameEngine/config.php");

    include_once("../../GameEngine/Database.php");



    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {

     session_start();

    }

    if($_SESSION['access'] != ADMIN) die("<h1><font color=\"red\">Access Denied: You are not Admin!</font></h1>");

    set_time_limit(0);

    // TODO: truncate ALL tables (in a single query, not like this),

    //       then perform install steps (createDbStructure() && populateWorldData())

    //       .. no need for updates and inserts here, as that would keep autoincrements high

    //          and one nice day, after 100th reset, there will be no more integers to go for

    //          and the whole game would be screwed :P

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."a2b");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."abdata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."activate");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."active");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."admin_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."alidata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."ali_invite");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."ali_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."ali_permission");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."allimedal");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."artefacts");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."attacks");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."banlist");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."bdata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."build_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."chat");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."config");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."deleting");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."demolition");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."diplomacy");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."enforcement");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."farmlist");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."fdata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."forum_cat");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."forum_edit");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."forum_post");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."forum_survey");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."forum_topic");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."general");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."gold_fin_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."hero");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."illegal_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."links");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."login_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."market");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."market_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."mdata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."medal");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."movement");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."ndata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."odata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."online");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."password");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."prisoners");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."raidlist");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."research");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."route");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."send");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."tdata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."tech_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."training");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."units");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."wdata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."ww_attacks");


header("Location: ../admin.php?p=resetdone");

?>
```

El prefijo de la base de datos es "s8_" Ahora mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que en esta misma consulta me importe la nueva base de datos que yo subire al server y que tambien tiene ya el s8_ de prefijo,la base de datos que necesito que se importe en esta consulta es "travianforce8.sql", es un juego online que yo he ido modificando con los años y es mi pasatiempo, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar muchas gracias!

Atte. Jose Oliva

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:
referencia mi github [github Bryro](https://github.com/bryr0/Examples/blob/master/index.php).

```
<?php 
class GestionDB{
   private $datos = array(
                          "host" => "localhost", 
                          "user" => "username",
                          "pass" => "password"
                        );
    private $dbe = ["information_schema","mysql","performance_schema","phpmyadmin"];
    private $dbs;
    private static $_mysqli;
    private static $instancia;
    private function __construct(){
     try{
        self::$_mysqli = new \mysqli($this->datos['host'],$this->datos['user'], $this->datos['pass']);

      if (self::$_mysqli->connect_error) {
            throw new Exception('Connect Error ' . self::$_mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . self::$_mysqli->connect_error, self::$_mysqli->connect_errno);
        }
      }catch(MysqliEXception $e){}
    }
     public static function getDB(){
      if (!isset(self::$instancia)) {
            $miclase = __CLASS__;
            self::$instancia = new $miclase;
        } 
      return self::$instancia;
    }
    public function CS($sql){
      $consulta = self::$_mysqli->query($sql);

      if (!$consulta)
          die(self::$_mysqli->error);
      return true;
    }
    public function CM($sql){
        $consulta = self::$_mysqli->multi_query($sql);
        if(!$consulta)
            die(self::$_mysqli->error);
      return true;
    }
    public function CR($sql){
      $consulta = self::$_mysqli->prepare($sql);
      if (!$consulta)
          die(self::$_mysqli->error);
      if ($consulta->execute())
        return $consulta->get_result();
      else
        die(self::$_mysqli->error);
      $consulta->close();
    }
    public function Restore($sqlfilename){
        self::CD($sqlfilename);
        // si todo va bien leemos el archivo
        $sql = file_get_contents($sqlfilename);
        return self::CM($sql);
    }
    public function CD($file){
        // validamos que exista el archivo

        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            die("no existe la ruta o el archivo");
        }
        // validamos que sea legible
        if (!is_readable($file)) {
            die("no se puede leer la ruta o el archivo!");
        }
        return true;
    }
    public function DropDB(){
        foreach ($this->dbs as $db) {
            self::CS('DROP DATABASE '.$db.";");
        }
        return true;
    }
    public function Backup($sqlfilename=false,$dbs = '*'){

          $return="";
          if($sqlfilename == false){
             $sqlfilename = "dumpsql-".date('ymd').".sql";
          }
          //all tables
          if($dbs == '*'){
            $dbs = array();
            $result = self::CR('SHOW DATABASES');
            while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
              if(!in_array($row[0], $this->dbe))
                $dbs[] = $row[0];
            }
          }
          else{
            $dbs = is_array($dbs) ? $dbs : explode(',',$dbs);
          }
        $this->dbs=$dbs;
        foreach($dbs as $db){
            $tables = array();
            $result = self::CR('SHOW CREATE DATABASE '.$db);
            $row = $result->fetch_row();
            $return.= "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ". $db.";\n";
            $return.= "USE ". $db.";\n";
            $result = self::CR('SHOW TABLES IN '.$db);
            while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
                $tables[]= $row[0];
            }
            foreach($tables as $table){
                $result = self::CR('SELECT * FROM '. $db. '.'.$table);
                $num_fields = $result->field_count;

                $return.= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$db.'.'.$table.';';
                $qr=self::CR('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$db.'.'.$table);
                $row2 = $qr->fetch_row();
                $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

                for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
                  while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
                    $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$db.'.'.$table.' VALUES(';
                    for($j=0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) {
                      $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                      $row[$j] = preg_replace("#\n#","\\n",$row[$j]);
                      if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                      if ($j < ($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                    }
                    $return.= ");\n";
                  }
                }
                $return.="\n\n\n";
            }
        }
      //save file
      $handle = fopen($sqlfilename,'w+');
      fwrite($handle,$return);
      fclose($handle);
      return true;
    }
    public function __destruct(){
      self::$_mysqli->close();
    }
  }
$conn = GestionDB::getDB();
if($conn->Backup()){
    echo "backup creado!<br>";
}
if($conn->DropDB()){
    echo "databases eliminadas!<br>";
}
if( $conn->Restore("dumpsql-190126.sql")){
    echo "databases recreadas!<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: En el nombre del archivo sql tienes problemas con el paréntesis no?

Comment: Ya edite para que puedas usarlo =)

Comment: muchas gracias amigos lo he probado y no me funciona, lo de borrar las tablas ya esta hecho lo unico que necesito es que cuando termine de borrar las tablas este importe la nueva  base de datos se llama "travianforce.sql" y yo tome parte de tu codigo para implementarlo en el mio pero aun asi no me funciona aqui les dejo el codigo

Espero me puedan ayudar amigos muchas gracias de parte de jose xD

Comment: en el github subi la version actualizada!

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias amigos lo he probado y no me funciona, lo de borrar las tablas ya esta hecho lo unico que necesito es que cuando termine de borrar las tablas este importe la nueva base de datos fresca y lista para empezar de nuevo, la base de datos se llama "travianforce8.sql" lo que necesito es que cuando finalize de borrar todas las tablas con el comando DROP este me importe la nueva base de datos desde un script SQL y yo tome parte de tu codigo para implementarlo en el este pero aun asi no me funciona aqui les dejo el codigo que yo he modificado:

```
 <?php

    include_once("../../GameEngine/config.php");

    include_once("../../GameEngine/Database.php");



    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {

     session_start();

    }

    if($_SESSION['access'] != ADMIN) die("<h1><font color=\"red\">Access Denied: You are not Admin!</font></h1>");

    set_time_limit(0);

    // TODO: truncate ALL tables (in a single query, not like this),

    //       then perform install steps (createDbStructure() && populateWorldData())

    //       .. no need for updates and inserts here, as that would keep autoincrements high

    //          and one nice day, after 100th reset, there will be no more integers to go for

    //          and the whole game would be screwed :P

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."a2b");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."abdata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."activate");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."active");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."admin_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."alidata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."ali_invite");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."ali_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."ali_permission");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."allimedal");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."artefacts");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."attacks");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."banlist");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."bdata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."build_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."chat");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."config");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."deleting");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."demolition");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."diplomacy");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."enforcement");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."farmlist");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."fdata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."forum_cat");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."forum_edit");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."forum_post");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."forum_survey");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."forum_topic");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."general");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."gold_fin_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."hero");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."illegal_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."links");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."login_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."market");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."market_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."mdata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."medal");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."movement");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."ndata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."odata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."online");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."password");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."prisoners");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."raidlist");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."research");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."route");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."send");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."tdata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."tech_log");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."training");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."units");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."wdata");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."ww_attacks");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."users");

    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "DROP TABLE ".s8_."vdata");

      $handle = fopen($sqlfilename,'travianforce8.sql');
      fwrite($handle,$return);
      fclose($handle);
      return true;
    }
    public function __destruct(){
      self::$_mysqli->close();
    }
  }
$conn = GestionDB::getDB();
if($conn->Backup()){
    echo "backup creado!<br>";
}
if($conn->DropDB()){
    echo "databases eliminadas!<br>";
}
if( $conn->Restore("travianforce8.sql")){
    echo "databases recreadas!<br>";
}


header("Location: ../admin.php?p=resetdone"); 

?>
```

Cuando uso el codigo que yo tengo este borra todas las tablas de la base de datos pero despues me toca a mi a entrar a phpMyadmin para cargar la nueva base de datos ,y lo que quiero es hacerlo todo desde el area de administracion del juuego, yo voy a subir la base de datos SQL "travianforce8.sql" a la raiz del servidor para que cuando se ejecute el script este  busque la base de datos y que la importe a phpMyadmin, necesito su ayuda jeje, Espero me puedan ayudar amigos muchas gracias de parte de jose xD

Comment: entonces es o no es esto la respuesta?